# What is the largest power of 2 that divides $200!/100!$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the largest power of 2 that divides $200!/100!$.

No use of calculator is allowed.
I had proceeded in a brute force method which i know regret..
I would like to know your methods.

Comment: Exact or approximations?

Comment: exact man.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find highest power of $2$ in $200!$ and $100!$, using [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)

In $200!$, highest power of $2$

$$=\lfloor 200/2 \rfloor +\lfloor 200/4 \rfloor +\lfloor 200/8 \rfloor +\lfloor 200/16 \rfloor +\lfloor 200/32 \rfloor +\lfloor 200/64 \rfloor +\lfloor 200/128 \rfloor $$

$$=100+50+25+12+6+3+1=197$$

In $100!$, highest power of $2$

$$=\lfloor 100/2 \rfloor +\lfloor 100/4 \rfloor +\lfloor 100/8 \rfloor +\lfloor 100/16 \rfloor +\lfloor 100/32 \rfloor +\lfloor 100/64 \rfloor$$

$$= 50 + 25+12+6+3+1 =97$$

Now, just subtract the two, and we get $100$ as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-The largest power of the prime $p$ dividing $n!$ is given by the very known formula
$$\lfloor\frac np\rfloor+\lfloor\frac {n}{p^2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac {n}{p^3}\rfloor+\cdots$$